# Git 'blob' versus 'commit' problems.

Tags: git, blob, commit

I have a project in which I want to embed a python module. I git cloned the python module and rearranged it in my python structure. Now when I try to add the python module in my git repository it is added as following:

```
100755 blob 7899dc9d74b1fbe3b1bf0e54a2480b68da2dddcc    code_base/frroleutils/entityutils/arktweetnlp/scripts/show.py
100755 blob a959deef0f9833e60b5446adefab6796f5f71449    code_base/frroleutils/entityutils/arktweetnlp/scripts/simple_tests.sh
100755 blob 80c8009bb48811962968bcf3c4705009f6497eb1    code_base/frroleutils/entityutils/arktweetnlp/scripts/toconll.py
100755 blob d712af76ca62b2fa1f2b93533cead693b96c053a    code_base/frroleutils/entityutils/arktweetnlp/twokenize.sh
100644 blob 24d5c14ece8f45018126d97232579b088396d2f8    code_base/frroleutils/entityutils/ners.py
100644 blob 347c43fba86db13c195c508614c1cb630f437794    code_base/frroleutils/entityutils/ners.pyc
160000 commit fbc6094e8634dd7b64c40d26c587ee074499b879  code_base/frroleutils/entityutils/twitter_nlp
100644 blob e7b4ac061b6b721bca87f52941a13f8438fd9b9b    code_base/frroleutils/utils.py
100755 blob af369b76f0fb7f4d0d3314919a4be0d1bd82ac06    code_base/init.py
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    code_base/location_script/Untitled Document
100644 blob 108cae5da47c8dadd1b21897dfdcf7a9a8a6d55b    code_base/location_script/__init__.py
100644 blob 5a1fef41e997e5c29037110f4d489e7628969dba    code_base/location_script/blacklist.list
100644 blob 5a1fef41e997e5c29037110f4d489e7628969dba    code_base/location_script/blacklist.list~
100644 blob d8fd99d73318712b4cde674fc235d50a771f2ba1    code_base/location_script/load.py
```

As you can see the python module is `twitter_nlp` and for strange reason, it's appearing as type 'commit' in my git repo tree.

A problem is that I'm unable to add any files under `twitter_nlp` in my git repo. I have no idea what is happening here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you move the files around? Did you use git mv?

Comment: Unfortunately No. I know it's bad, but that is the case.

Comment: You might want to repeat the steps using git mv?

Answer (score 1):

The `mode 160000` indicates that it's a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).  See also [Rename a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4526910/1256452).