# Issue with updating Hugo blogdown's academic theme folder using git, GitHub desktop

Tags: git, rstudio, hugo, blogdown, github-desktop

### Issue

I’ve been having some issues with git/GitHub desktop sync issues with Hugo Blogdown theme folder (academic). After renaming/updating, I've a 'missing themes folder'. Once this is fixed, I'll be able to host my Hugo Blogdown website w/ academic theme.  If anyone has had similar issues, please advise. Thanks!

#### Environment

I work with macOS High Sierra (`v10.13.4`) and RStudio (`v1.2.616`) w/ Hugo (`v0.30`) blogdown (`v0.6.3`) and the academic theme.

### Previously raised this issue here

- [GitHub: Desktop](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4784)
- [GitHub: Hugo-academic](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/563)
- [Hugo discourse](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/issue-with-updating-hugo-theme-folder-git-github-desktop/12293)

I'm posting it again here on Stack Exchange so as to get a quick resolution.

### Updating the Hugo theme (academic)

I tried to update the theme folder to make sure I have the latest version with the recent fixes+suggestions. However, I've been having trouble with it the past few times. It probably started with my renaming the folder name from Hugo-academic to academic (back and forth) using RStudio+terminal. Now, I am not able to add the themes folder to my online GitHub repo no matter what I fix. Not sure where the underlying problem is: git/GitHub desktop, Hugo blogdown or the academic theme issue. Hence, I've used all these `tags`!

### Missing GitHub folder

Assuming that it was a GitHub desktop issue, I initially posted my concern [here](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4784) (please see screenshots of error messages). I followed the steps for academic theme update [here](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/update/) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712756/1363815) for `git submodule add`.

Based on my most recent update in [this issue](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4784), the commit did happen. *Bottom line*: I don't see the folder on GitHub, yet!

[image: missing academic folder]

Clearly, I'm missing something. I'd appreciate any troubleshooting help, and please let me know if you need any further clarification on the question. thank you!!

*ps*. Of the [suggested modes](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/update/), I used the zip option to update the academic folder even though I may have used git clone option earlier. I am having trouble with either/all options now.

Comment: completely deleting the academic folder and running `git clone https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic academic/` followed by add+commit steps worked this time! wonder what was wrong earlier, but the problem has been temporarily fixed. Didn't try renaming again or updating using the .zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Updating via Git cloning - as explained in the [wonderful doc pages](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/update/) by George Cushen – did not work for me too. I changed the name of the remote repository from `origin` to `upstream`and did all the other following commands. But there was no response at all in the terminal.

It seems there is some incompatibility between R/RStudio/blogdown/GitHub as listing the available updates didn't work either. See also the answer by George Cushen at his [GitHub repo](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/563).

> It appears that this issue is mainly related to Git/Hugo in general and their integration with RStudio/Blogdown.

So I changed the method for updating. I succeeded with the ZIP method without any problem.