# Best practice for updating Hugo academic theme installed with install_hugo()

Tags: r, git, hugo, blogdown

Since I did not use `git clone` to install the Hugo academic theme with R `blogdown`, and since I use my own git repository to manage the entire `blogdown` directory structure (which includes `theme`) it seems to be complicated to use git to update the academic theme as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704330).  What is the best approach for updating the academic theme on an existing R `blogdown` structure?

Comment: Could you run `blogdown::install_theme` with `force = TRUE`? Customizations to the theme would be lost though..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally I'd recommend *not* to update a Hugo theme unless you run into theme bugs or see new features in the newer version of the theme that you really need. It is kind of unpredictable what will happen if you update a theme. That said, I use git submodules to manage Hugo themes [myself](https://github.com/rbind/yihui/tree/master/themes) (and I don't update the submodule unless I really need a newer version). There is more information about this in the [Appendix D.7 of the **blogdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/version-control.html).