# How do I change a submodule's name?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've spent a considerable amount of time reading through this:
[Rename a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526910/rename-a-git-submodule)

However my case is actually a bit different. I've already renamed/moved the submodules, but I've noticed that the "name" of the module is the name I initially had when I first added the module.

I believe the `--name` property can only be used when a module is initially added. But just incase, I thought I'd ask:

Can I change the "name" of the module once it's already been moved? I want to have the entry in the `.gitmodules` and `.git/config` changed, as well as the directory structure inside of `.git/modules/*`

I'm trying to prevent having to remove the modules (there's quite a few) and then re-add them all.

For reference, here's what a current module record in my `.gitmodules` file looks like:

```
[submodule "TurtlePHP/application/vendors/PHP-Pixabay"]
    path = TurtlePHP/application/vendors/submodules/PHP-Pixabay
    url = git@github.com:onassar/PHP-Pixabay.git
```

And here's what I want it to be:

```
[submodule "TurtlePHP/application/vendors/submodules/PHP-Pixabay"]
    path = TurtlePHP/application/vendors/submodules/PHP-Pixabay
    url = git@github.com:onassar/PHP-Pixabay.git
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think renaming sections in `.git/config` and `.gitmodules` is just fine:

```
git config                --rename-section submodule.TurtlePHP/application/vendors/PHP-Pixabay submodule.TurtlePHP/application/vendors/submodules/PHP-Pixabay
git config -f .gitmodules --rename-section submodule.TurtlePHP/application/vendors/PHP-Pixabay submodule.TurtlePHP/application/vendors/submodules/PHP-Pixabay
```

Comment: What about the actual directory structure within `/.git/modules`?

Comment: In the context of CLI/git commands, renaming/moving a module is different than changing it's name. Renaming/moving moves the directory and references within `.gitmodules` and `.git/config`, whereas _changing the name_ changes the name associated with that submodule.

Comment: The linked question has many good answers, aren't they enough? Just a week ago a I restructured and renamed a submodule from `xxx-yyy` to `xxx/yyy`. It was really simple.

Comment: Moving/renaming a submodule is different than actually changing the module's `name`. Have you looked into the `.gitmodules` file, and checked out the name? It's possible (but not 100%) that the name itself it incorrect, if the name was originally defined to be the relative path to the submodule.