# How to change a git submodule's name only, leaving its path unchanged?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Suppose that a `.gitmodules` file includes the following lines

```
[submodule "sub/x"]
    path = sub/x
```

...which resulted from a command of the form

```
git submodule add $url sub/x
```

After the fact (and after having added several commits, both to the superproject as well as the submodule), I realize that I should have run this instead:

```
git submodule add --name x $url sub/x
```

...so that the two lines in the `.gitmodules` file corresponding to the two quoted earlier would have been

```
[submodule "x"]
    path = sub/x
```

I want to fix the superproject so that the *name* of the submodule is `x` rather than `sub/x`, but the *path* remains `sub/x`<sup>1</sup>.

My immediate interest is in learning how to *fix the history* (e.g. through an interactive rebase) of the superproject, so that in the end the repo looks as if the second `git submodule add` command was the one used from the beginning.  (FWIW, this repo has not yet been published, though I do intend to do so.)  For future reference, however, I am also interested in learning how to do this without modifying the history, i.e. by adding one or more new commits to it.

I have tried to remove the submodule and add it again (based on the `git submodule deinit` recipe given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/559827)), but I quickly find myself in a mess.  (I think that part of the problem is that, as I already mentioned, I have added several commits to the submodule, made corresponding updates to the superproject's submodule information, along the way.)

Therefore, I am hoping to find more direct guidance on how to do this renaming.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> There is an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526910/rename-a-git-submodule) whose title suggests that it is asking exactly the question I am asking here, but in fact that post is asking for not only how to rename the submodule, but also *how to change its path*.  It turns out that most of the content in the answers to that question focus on the problem of changing the module's path.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

I think renaming sections in `.git/config` and `.gitmodules` is just fine:

```
git config                --rename-section submodule.sub/x submodule.x
git config -f .gitmodules --rename-section submodule.sub/x submodule.x
git add .gitmodules
git commit -m "Rename submodule.sub/x -> submodule.x"
```

Comment: Note that after modifying the `.gitmodules` file, you should generally add and commit it. Committing the rename by itself seems sensible.