# How can I rename a git repository with submodules?

Tags: git, repository, git-submodules

I have a git repository with submodules in the directory `projects/myRepo` and I want to rename the directory to `projects/my-repo`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041993/how-to-rename-a-git-project-name) question it can simply be done with `mv`. But in a repo with submodules git keeps telling me

> fatal: Not a git repository: projects/myRepo/.git/path/to/submodule```

even for `git status`.

Submodule config:

```
[submodule "path/to/submodule"]  
   path = path/to/submodule  
   url = https://github.com/user/projectName.git
```

Somehow the 'internal path' for the submodule does not get updated?! Is there a way to tell git to update these submodule paths?

Comment: That should just work. What's in the .gitmodule file?

Comment: @Weston, please see my updated question. But even when I remove this section it from the .gitmodules file the same error appears. When I rename the parent dir back to the original name git does no longer complain.

Comment: Hmm.. I just tried making a test repo with a submodule. Then I cloned it, init'ed and updated the submodule in the clone, and then renamed the clone with mv. All seems to work as expected...?

Comment: Yes, I tried the same with a fresh clone, which also worked without problems - it's just that particular repo, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878860/how-can-i-rename-a-git-repository-with-submodules#comment12628515_9885513

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [Weston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/983618/weston)'s test (clone, init and update of a submodule in a cloned repo) worked as expected when renaming the directory including said submodule, I suspect something must have been wrong in the submodule `.git` itself in your original Git repo submodule.

You could compare/look for any file referencing '`myRepo`' in that first submodule.
you can also compare the content of the two submodules (the first one you tried to rename, and the second one included in the repo that you cloned)

Comment: Please note the names here.. I, not the OP, made said test. :-) But maybe OP should make the same test to verify his installation.

Comment: @Weston sorry, I wasn't completely awake when I wrote this ;)

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem, so I think I messed something up while refactoring the project. If I got the time I'll investigate the broken repo, until then I created a new clone, which works fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same error after changing my project directory.  I have an iOS 6 XCode 4 project but that shouldn't matter.

For each submodule, you need to change the absolute path that it thinks it's in.  The path is set in the .git file for that submodule.  .git in a submodule is a *file* as opposed to a *directory* in a standard git directory.

For each submodule, change the .gitdir line in the .git file.  Here is an example from my project:

File: /path/to/project/submodules/RestKit/.git

**Before**
gitdir: /path/to/project//.git/modules/submodules/RestKit

**After**
gitdir: /path/to/project//.git/modules/submodules/RestKit

Comment: I also had to change my **worktree** path in .git/modules/path/to/project/submodules/RestKit/config

Answer (score 3):

I did experience exactly the same behavior. I managed to fix it by deleting directories with submodules, recreating them as empty directories with the right name and then running `git submodule update --init` to reinitialize them. All fixed now. Probably some permission problems (I retrieved those directories from backup earlier and permissions on them are sometimes strange).

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same problem to rename the submodule and finally I fixed it by using the following steps:

Assume the old module name is `old/module` and the new one is `new/module/path`

1. at the root of the repo (`repo_root`), `mv old/module new/module/path`
2. go to `.git/modules`

   1. `mv old/module new/module/path` (create the folder first if necessary)
   2. change `new/module/name/config`: update the `worktree` entry. It should be the relative path from this config file to `repo_root/new/module/path`
3. go to `repo_root` and edit `new/module/path/.git`, change the `gitdir` to the relative path from this file to `repo_root/.git/modules/new/module/path`
4. change `.git/config` of the master repo: find the line containing `[submodule "old/module"]` and update to `[submodule "new/module/path"]`