# git status returns fatal: Not a git repository but .git exists and HEAD has proper permissions

Tags: git

When I run git status on my repo I get `fatal: Not a git repository: /my repo/.git/modules/docs`

I've checked and .git exists and contains HEAD with the proper permissions. I can run various other commands fine. If I run git gui it opens fine and will list a couple of the changed files, but is missing a lot of them.

I'm guessing there may be some sort of corruption in HEAD, not sure though. Any idea how to fix this without wiping out the whole repo?

Update: I realized that I had changed the name of the repo's directory. The directory being referenced in the error is the old name of the directory. So my current repo is at `/new dir/.git` but the error is saying `Not a git repository: /old dir/.git/modules/docs`. So maybe git is confused?

Comment: Are you nesting git repositories?

Comment: @nes1983 I do have several submodules, however this issue is with the main repo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally sorted out that the issue was due to an issue with one of the submodules. Simply renaming the repo directory caused a conflict with that submodule. After seeing the discussion in [How can I rename a git repository with submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878860/how-can-i-rename-a-git-repository-with-submodules) I realized that cloning the repo is a better way to go instead of renaming the directory and that solved the issue with the submodule.

Comment: Recovering from this problem only takes two small manual edits per submodule. For me that's easier than re-cloning the repository and all its submodule(s).

Comment: @JoshFarneman How should I (newbie) understand what you've done. pls provide `clear code` before and after. so one can understand what is required.

Comment: But what If I don't want to lose my local branches. ? Please help me what to do in such a scenario.

Answer (score 87):

These two files contains absolute submodule path:

```
{submodule}/.git
.git/modules/{submodule}/config
```

So, if you moved the repo, the absolute path in these two files are not valid, and cause the 'not a git repository' error. Just fix these files manually.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well for me. However, the second path was a bit shorter for me: `.git/modules/{submodule}/config` (I'm using git version 1.7.9.5 on Ubuntu)

Comment: I just moved from PC to Mac and having the same problem. I updated the path in those two files, and the new path is correct, but I'm still getting `fatal: Not a git repository`. There is a .git file in that location, so maybe I'm missing something else?

Comment: Just a note here, for me the config file has a relative path unlike the .git file.

Answer (score 43):

Former versions of git used an absolute path to locate the gitdir of a submodule. The solution is as follows:

1. Upgrade git to the [latest version](http://git-scm.com/download/). Some says you'll need at least version 1.7.10. I just successfully solved the issue with git 1.8.3.
2. Delete all the broken submodule folders: `rm -rf broken_submodule_folder`
3. Update the registered submodules: `git submodule update`. You should see the submodules being checked out.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but just to let other people know: it's still a good answer in 2018. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

In my case the problem was the .git/HEAD file didn't point anywhere, it just contained a sequence of strange characters. I copied the contents of .git/ORIG_HEAD to .git/HEAD and it worked again.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22604593/813122)

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue by reseting all git-submodules with

```
rm -rf .git/modules
git submodule update --init
```

Comment: Wow! Just worked for me! In my case I accidentally made a "rm -r" with no wildcard matching. It wiped a couple of files from the project root before being stopped for some prompt.

Answer (score 4):

Following @ax003d [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13893585/102353), you could replace all old paths (`old/path`) with the new path (`new/path`) using this command:

```
find . -type f \( -name ".git" -o \( -path "*.git/modules/*" -name config \) \)  -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e "s#old/path#new/path#g"
```

You might want to check what the old paths look like before replacing them:

```
find . -type f \( -name ".git" -o \( -path "*.git/modules/*" -name config \) \)  -print0 | xargs -0 grep --colour "old/path"
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution :

1) Look into the HEAD file (under .git) ->
If it is corrupted (contains some random values), replace the content with this text
'ref: refs/heads/develop' (develop is the last branch I was working on)

2) try - git status.

3) If step 2 doesn't solve your issue, try these commands (may not work for all but worth a try)

rm -f .git/index
git reset

4) git will give you unstaged files after reset.
keep or discard as per your wish

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it for me. I'm guessing my HEAD file somehow got corrupted. No submodules like OP, just simply receiving the dreadful "Fatal: not a git repository" all of a sudden out of nowhere

Comment: This happened to me when i was doing git checkout then it hanged so i restarted the pc. thank you mate.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue with submodules as well, but after analyzing the two files

{submodule}/.git
.git/modules/submodules/{submodule}/config

I realized that in my case this was not an issue.

After a little research I have found that in my case I had to add the git (command : module add git) and the error disappeared.

Comment: In Linux command prompt while running - module add got, I get the following error. module: command not found