# How to extract a git repository that is inside another one

Tags: git, github, repository

I created by mistake a local repository and then I cloned my remote repository inside of that repository. Therefore, now my cloned repo is trapped in this outer repository. is there a way I can extract it?

Comment: Just move the directory, or delete it and re-clone to the correct location?

Comment: but I have made changes that I need to push so would just moving the directory solve it?

Comment: I would expect so, the git state is in the .git directory inside the repo directory.

Comment: @jonrsharpe May need fixing in [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13893585/5987698).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @jonrsharpe's comment, just move the cloned directory.

On unix-like systems:

```
$ cd /base/path/repoA/some/repoB
$ git remote -v     ## shows the inner repoB
$ cd ..
$ git remote -v     ## shows the outer repoA
$ git status        ## shows repoB/ as untracked
$ mv repoB /base/path
```

Then you can push/commit/etc as needed

```
$ cd /base/path/repoB
$ git commit . . .
$ git push
```

You don't have to move it to push changes (git will detect which repo you are working in by searching up your directory path and using the first one).