# How to rename a git repo (project) which contains submodules in its subdirectories

Tags: git, git-submodules

I never expect renaming a git repo, which, more specifically, is the top-level folder holds the project, would be so hard. Yes, the project containing some submodules, but it is the **top-level folder** that needs renaming, not the **submodule folder**. Git, it seems, records some odd *absolute paths* in its submodule mechanisms.

Let's assume that

1. All your projects locate in `/tmp`.
2. You've got a `proj_master` and `proj_mod`.
3. You clone `porj_master` as `proj_ALL` then clone `prom_mod` as a submodule in it.
4. You rename `proj_ALL` to `proj_onebillion`. Then black magic happens.

The following steps will reproduce the problem I mentioned. The version of git I use is:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.9.5
```

---

1. Initialize `proj_master`.

   ```
   $ cd /tmp
   $ mkdir proj_master; cd proj_master
   $ git init .
   $ touch README
   $ git add .; git commit -m "hello proj_master"
   ```
2. Initialize `proj_mod`.

   ```
   $ cd /tmp
   $ mkdir proj_mod; cd proj_mod
   $ git init .
   $ touch README
   $ git add .; git commit -m "hello proj_mod"
   ```
3. Clone `proj_master` as `proj_ALL` and clone `proj_mod` as a submodule.

   ```
   $ cd /tmp
   $ git clone proj_master proj_ALL
   $ cd proj_ALL
   $ git submodule add /tmp/proj_mod ./mod
   $ git add .; git commit -m "hello proj_ALL"
   $ git status   % Everything is OK.
   ```
4. Rename `proj_ALL` to `proj_onebillion`. Encounter a fatal error.

   ```
   $ cd /tmp
   $ mv proj_ALL proj_onebillion
   $ cd proj_onebillion
   $ git status
   fatal: Not a git repository: /tmp/proj_ALL/.git/modules/mod
   ```

---

One thing to notice is the `.git` file in the submodule directory.

```
$ cat /tmp/proj_ALL/mod/.git 
gitdir: /tmp/proj_ALL/.git/modules/mod
```

Yeah, an absolute path. For the first time, I realize that git is aware of something outside the scope of the top-level repo folder.

That's it. I repeat that one more time that I rename the top-level project folder, not the submodule folder. I check [schmuck's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878860/how-can-i-rename-a-git-repository-with-submodules), which tried to rename the submodule folder, therefore seems not so helpful to my problem.

If I miss something that should have been read before, I apologize. To all guys, any advice is welcomed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a couple of options, they end up being the same thing:

**clone again**

Instead of renaming the folder - just clone again

```
$ cd /project/original
$ cd ..
$ mkdir moved
$ git init
$ git pull ../original master
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

Compare `original/.git/config` to `moved/.git/config` and address any significant differences ([missing branches need creating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4754797/761202) - missing remotes just need adding to the config file).

**fix paths**

You can rename your project folder, it just needs a little tweaking.

- Fix your submodule .git file references.

I.e. these files:

```
$ cd /project/moved
$ find -name .git -type f
```

All you need to do is edit them to point at the right directory

- Fix your submodule .git config files

I.e. these files:

```
$ cd /project/moved
$ find .git/modules/ -name config
```

Here, update the `worktree` setting:

```
[core]
    ...
    worktree = /original/path/submodule
```

To

```
[core]
    ...
    worktree = /moved/path/submodule
```

And that's it.

**A note about versions**

1.7.8 introduced the use of a .git file for submodules and [used absolute paths](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/193492), this was fixed in 1.7.10 - therefore the problem only applies to git repos created with git version 1.7.8, and 1.7.9.

Comment: Thanks, AD7six. Your trick fixes my problem. I'm just curious about why git uses such a nasty approach ("absolute path") in its recent release.

Comment: Others are complaining about these issues too. Check ["Annoying absolute path for "core.worktree" to submodule"](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/193492). Good news is that, in git-1.7.10, *relative path* will be back and *absolute path* will go away.

Comment: I had noticed that one of my machines used relative paths, but hadn't checked the versions - I added that info to the answer after a quick bit of confirmatory research.

Answer (score 5):

When moving a project that has git submodules from one folder to another, on the same machine, there are some hardcoded links that have to be updated.

First, all submodules have a .git file where they store the absolute path to their git configuration folder ( these are inside the main's project .git folder, grouped into the modules folder). To fix all of these, run the following command from the root of the main project:

```
find . -name .git -print0 -type f | xargs -0 sed -i 's|<OLD PATH>|<NEW PATH>|g'
```

Second, the configuration files for the git submodules have a line where the working directory is saved, also absolute. To update all of the references at once, run the following command from the root of the main project:

```
find . -name config -print0 -type f | xargs -0 sed -i 's|<OLD PATH>|<NEW PATH>|g'
```

The assumptions made are that your OS is some form of *nix, and that you have the package sed installed.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to check each sub-module's `gitdir`.

It should be in sub-module's folder `.git` file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually modify two files

```
.git/modules/<path-to-submodule>/config
<path-to-submodule>/.git
```