# How to change what git tracks

Tags: git, github

How do I make git move its tracking from the current directory, to that of a directory within the current directory.
(What it is now)

```
/current_dir/
  /dir_i_want_to_track/
    ...
    ...
```

I want to track `dir_i_want_to_track` but right now its tracking `current_dir`
(What I want)

```
/dir_i_want_to_track/
  ...
  ...
```

Edit for clarification @AD7six

These directories are within a repo. I started initializing the repo at `/current_dir`, and so git has been tracking all changes within `/current_dir/`. However, moving forward I want git to track all changes one directory deeper at `/dir_i_want_to_track/`, ignoring the other directories within `/current_dir/`., so that when I go onto the repo it only shows

```
/dir_i_want_to_track/
...
```

and not the other directories.

(I'd also like to keep a history of all previous commits)

Comment: I'm curious what circumstances lead to this question - was it e.g. a project that got bigger and needs to be split up, or the first git repo created for 'my projects' and now you've got two projects or etc.? I ask as the question can be clarified and made more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Do it slow and steady

The solution proposed here is the combination of 2 simple tasks that require no advanced git knowledge:

- Move the git repository
- Move files *in* a git repository

Consider the following, which simulates the state in the question:

```sh
mkdir -p /tmp/current_dir/dir_i_want_to_track
touch /tmp/current_dir/dir_i_want_to_track/README.md
cd /tmp/current_dir
git init
git add dir_i_want_to_track/README.md
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Here's our start state:

```sh
cd /tmp/current_dir
tree
.
└── dir_i_want_to_track
    └── README.md

1 directory, 1 file
```

### Move the git repository

Git does not care what the path is to a local repository (except for some [edge cases in older versions of git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10667194/761202)) - so just rename like you would any other folder. In this step we will rename `current_dir` such that it is `current_dir/dir_i_want_to_track`.

From the parent directory:

```sh
cd /tmp
mv current_dir current_dir_moved
mkdir current_dir
mv current_dir_moved current_dir/dir_i_want_to_track
```

That will achieve this intermediary state:

```
cd /tmp/current_dir
tree
.
└── dir_i_want_to_track
    └── dir_i_want_to_track
        └── README.md

2 directories, 1 file
```

Note that at this point `current_dir` is no longer a git repository.

### Move files *in* a git repository

Moving files in git is done with [git mv](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv):

```
cd /tmp/current_dir/dir_i_want_to_track
git mv dir_i_want_to_track/* .
git commit -m "move everything one dir up"
```

Thus achieving our desired end state:

```
cd /tmp/current_dir/dir_i_want_to_track
tree
.
└── README.md
0 directories, 1 file
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there could be unexpected behaviors, you can do it this was:

1. Make sure your repository is clean (make a commit if it's not).
2. Move the hidden directory called `.git` and located in `current_dir` to `dir_i_want_to_track`.
3. From your new repository, run a `git add --all` and a `git commit -m "Change root of repo"`

By doing that, your Git history will tell you you "moved" a bunch of files from a subdirectory to the main directory and that you deleted all the files located in the main directory.

Comment: `git add -u` will prevent adding untracked files to that 'changed root' commit. I wrote an answer that doesn't involve knowing any special git knowledge, as 'just' moving the .git folder I think kinda hides what is happening from Git's perspective and potentially creates confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try [git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#Documentation/git-filter-branch.txt---subdirectory-filterltdirectorygt). Say you are now on the branch `foo`.

```
# backup the current branch foo
git branch foo_backup 

# rewrite the branch foo
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter dir_i_want_to_track
```

The branch `foo` gets rewritten. The commits that don't touch `dir_i_want_to_track` will be empty commits. In most cases, you don't want to keep them. `--prune-empty` instructs to remove these empty commits on the new branch.

`git filter-branch` gives a warning that suggests you use other tools like `git filter-repo`. So you could also try these tools.

After the new branch is created, you need to use `git push --force origin foo:foo` to update the branch `foo` in the remote repository. Make sure that no one else is updating `foo` while you are rewriting and uploading it, otherwise their work might get lost.

Update: as @AD7six pointed out, you may want to keep the history. If so, just make a new commit that tracks `dir_i_want_to_track` as the root directory.

```
# if you have run the previous commands and rewritten the branch, first go back to the previous foo.
# if not, skip the following command.
git reset foo_backup --hard

# create a new commit based on the current head and merge it
git merge $(git commit-tree -p HEAD -m "xxx" HEAD:dir_i_want_to_track)

# amend the commit message
git commit --amend
```

The `git commit-tree` part creates a new commit. Its parent is the `foo` head, its commit message is `xxx` and its root tree is the version of `dir_i_want_to_track` in the `foo` head. This way, the branch is not rewritten. Instead, it's just like that you remove all the other directories and files, move everything inside `dir_i_want_to_track` to the root directory of the repository, and then make a new commit.

Comment: There’s no mention of wanting to rewrite history in the question, unless asked for this seems an easy way for a less experienced git user to make a mess.