# Changing Git remote URL updates fetch but not push

Tags: git, ssh

I am attempting to change the remote URL of my origin branch in Git. All I want to change is the SSH port. First, listing my remote origins gives me this:

```
git remote -v


origin  user@example.com:package/name.git (fetch)
origin  user@example.com:package/name.git (push)
```

Then, I run the `set-url` command to change my origin URL:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://user@example.com:XX/package/name.git    (XX is my port #)
```

Now, I can fetch without issue, but pushing my branch to origin doesn't work, because the push URL didn't change. Listing my remotes again I get this:

```
git remote -v


origin  ssh://user@example.com:XX/package/name.git (fetch)
origin  user@example.com:package/name.git (push)
```

**Why did my `set-url` command only change the fetch URL?**

Comment: If you type `man git-remote` on the command line, you can find this information easily. This works for almost all git commands, for instance `man git-add`, `man git-push`, and so on.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From `git-remote` manual:

```
set-url
    Changes URL remote points to. Sets first URL remote points to matching regex <oldurl> (first URL if no <oldurl> is given) to <newurl>. If <oldurl> doesn’t match any URL,
    error occurs and nothing is changed.

    With --push, push URLs are manipulated instead of fetch URLs.
```

So you should additionally execute:

```
git remote set-url --push origin ssh://user@example.com:XX/package/name.git
```

Comment: this does work although it doesn't explain why it didn't update both as it is supposed to

Comment: @JackJames: Right, I was pretty sure that this command set only fetch url by default. Now I was trying to find exact description in documentation but I only found several inconsistent blog posts e.g. [this one](http://blog.yuriy.tymch.uk/2012/05/different-git-push-pullfetch-urls.html) ant [this one](http://sushihangover.github.io/git-set-up-a-fetch-only-remote/) that tells that if push is not set, fetch is used as fallback. I will probably look into [source code](https://github.com/git/git) to find out.

Comment: @running.t I can't find any option for `pull` remote address, is fetch remote address same with pull?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari: Well, in [git-pull documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_description) you can find out that `pull` is in fact `fetch` followed by `merge`. So yes, fetch remote address is the one used when you call `git pull`.

Comment: Is there a way to change both url's with one command?

Answer (score 10):

As long as the config file for the repo in question contains an entry for the push URL, `set-url` will only update the fetch URL by default.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = fetch.git
    fetch = ...
    pushurl = push.git
```

As the answer of running.t explains, you can use `set-url --push` to change this entry. However, you will have to keep doing this every time the URL changes.

To restore the default behavior of `set-url` (which changes both URLs at once), just delete the entry from the config. Or delete it using `set-url --delete`:

```
git remote set-url --delete --push origin push.git
```

As for why a repository would ever contain a separate push url without you adding it: Some git clients like Sourcetree "helpfully" do this.

Comment: This answer was helpful to understand why `git remote set-url` was changing both URLs for me, when I actually wanted it to only change the fetch one