# Changing project name in GitHub and Atom

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

I'm building a website with React using Atom, which is connected to my GitHub account. Both the project name on GitHub and the local project folder name are the same "symbol-neural-network":

**How do I can correctly rename both the project name on both GitHub and Atom (project folder) so that they stay syncronized and Atom recognizes it's the same project?**

[image]

I thought of just renaming the project on GitHub, but I don't want to risk it. Also I believe I originally created the project first on Atom locally and then pushed it as a new repository to GitHub.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub documentation on [renaming a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.14/user/articles/renaming-a-repository) is clear how to do things. Generally, you can simply rename your repo to whatever you want and you can also update your remote on the local machine. Nothing will be lost. Your local machine will still track your remote.

As for the project folder, just rename that as well to whatever you want. Git does not care what the folder it is and how it's called.

This is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041993/how-do-i-rename-a-git-repository) that explains how to do it and what the different steps are.

Comment: Great! I'm glad this helped :)