# How to Remove Github Repositories

Tags: linux, windows, git, repository, command-line-interface

March 12, 2021

There is a repository on git that I'm trying to erase.  I set it up for initial practice, but now, I don't want to use it because the name is dumb (created it in a hurry)  I need to get rid if it, because the PC keeps trying to reference it when I use Git.  I just need to use my newer (better named) repository.  I'm not familiar with the git cli in the least.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I rename a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041993/how-do-i-rename-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Git creates a hidden `.git` folder when you initialize or clone a repository. Delete that folder to get rid of the repo.

From the command line, you can delete it with `rd /S/Q .git` (Windows) or `rm -rf .git` (Mac/Linux).

If you're wanting to remove a repository from GitHub, you can do that via `Settings -> Options -> Delete this repository`

Comment: I tried the windows commands in Powershell, and at the dos prompt, but they're not working.  The username is what's the sticking point.  I just quickly made it up out of thin air, and then tried setting up a new username.  I'd re-assign the user to the one that's  better, but don't know how.  I did try the rd /S/Q .git, but it's hanging up.