# How do I rename my *local* git repository after renaming the remote repo (Visual Studio 2022)?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a C#/netcoreapp3.1 Visual Studio 2022 solution on Windows 10.  I successfully renamed the remote repo, which is hosted on Azure DevOps.  I have also successfully updated my solution's remote settings to point to the new remote URL.

But I can't figure out a simple way to rename my *local* repo.  I went into all the Git and repository-related settings screens, but can't find an option for doing so.  It appears that I can only rename branches within a repo. but not the repo itself.  Nor does there appear to be any `git` command for doing so.  What do I do?

Here's the screenshot, which still displays the old name:

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"rename [the] local repo"*? If renaming the folder that contains your clone isn't enough, you'll need to clarify.

Comment: @madreflection In the bottom righthand corner of VS, it still shows the old name of the repo instead of the new name.  I have posted a screenshot in my original question.

Comment: That's the name of the containing folder.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I merely needed to rename the containing folder.  Thanks @madreflection

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can do that is, edit the repo name in `.git/description` file. As described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041993/how-do-i-rename-a-git-repository)